# WP Widget - missing fields in Frontend

Tags: php, wordpress, widget

I've created a plugin to integrate a widget. The widget is to collect various data and then output in a sidebar .
The data is collected apparently because they appear in the backend. However, they will not transferred to the frontend.

Title - Picture Name - Description - Link - Link Text

Except for the last two fields all are displayed in the frontend. Only just link and linktext does not show up.

Can anyone help me with this problem?

Thank you in advance !!!

```
<?php
/*
Plugin Name: Widget-Plugin
Plugin URI: http://www.123456.de
Description: Plugin zur Anzeige eines Widgets
Version: 1.0
*/

class wp_widget_plugin extends WP_Widget {

// constructor
function wp_widget_plugin() {
    parent::WP_Widget(false, $name = __('widget Widget', 'wp_widget_plugin') );
}   


// widget form creation
function form($instance) {

// Check values
if( $instance) {
     $title = esc_attr($instance['title']);
     $text = esc_attr($instance['text']);
     $textarea = esc_textarea($instance['textarea']);
     $select = esc_attr($instance['select']); 
     $hlink = esc_attr($instance['hlink']);
     $hlinktext = esc_attr($instance['hlinktext']);
} else {
     $title = '';
     $text = '';
     $textarea = '';
     $select = '';
     $hlink = '';
     $hlinktext = '';
}
?>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>">Titel</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('title'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('title'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $title; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>">Bildname</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('text'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('text'); ?>" type="text" value="<?php echo $text; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>">Beschreibung</label>
<textarea class="widefat" rows="8" cols="20" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('textarea'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('textarea'); ?>"><?php echo $textarea; ?></textarea>
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('hlink'); ?>">Link</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('hlink'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('hlink'); ?>" value="<?php echo $hlink; ?>" />
</p>

<p>
<label for="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('hlinktext'); ?>">Linktext</label>
<input class="widefat" id="<?php echo $this->get_field_id('hlinktext'); ?>" name="<?php echo $this->get_field_name('hlinktext'); ?>" value="<?php echo $hlinktext; ?>" />
</p>

<?php
}

// update widget
function update($new_instance, $old_instance) {
    $instance = $old_instance;
    // Fields
    $instance['title'] = strip_tags($new_instance['title']);
    $instance['text'] = strip_tags($new_instance['text']);
    $instance['hlink'] = strip_tags($new_instance['hlink']);
    $instance['hlinktext'] = strip_tags($new_instance['hlinktext']);
    if ( current_user_can('unfiltered_html') )
    $instance['textarea'] =  $new_instance['textarea'];
else
    $instance['textarea'] = stripslashes( wp_filter_post_kses( addslashes($new_instance['textarea']) ) );
    return $instance;
}

// display widget
function widget($args, $instance) {
    extract( $args );

    // these are the widget options
    $title = apply_filters('widget_title', $instance['title']);

    $text = $instance['text'];

    $textarea = apply_filters( 'widget_textarea', empty( $instance['textarea'] ) ? '' : $instance['textarea'], $instance );
    echo $before_widget;

    // Display the widget
    echo '<div class="h-widget">';

        if ( $title ) {
          echo '<div class="con-title"><h2>' . $title . '</h2></div>';
        }

        if( $text ) {
          echo '<div class="con-img"><img src="../wp-content/uploads/' . $text . '.jpg"></div>';
        }
        echo '<div class="con-text">';
        if( $textarea ) {
        echo wpautop($textarea); 
        }
        echo '</div>';

        echo '<div class="con-title"><h2><a href="';
        if( $hlink ) {
            echo ' . $hlink . ';
        }
        echo '">';
        if( $hlinktext ) {
            echo ' . $hlinktext . ';
        }
        echo '</a></h2></div>';
    echo '</div>';
echo $after_widget;
}
}

// register widget
add_action('widgets_init', create_function('', 'return            r egister_widget("wp_widget_plugin");'));



?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$hlink` and `$hlinktext` are not defined. You should define them before outputting the HTML (probably before the `echo $before_widget;` line) like so:

```
$hlink = $instance['hlink'];
$hlinktext = $instance['hlinktext'];
```